# Vue3 When data is sent to the store file, an error occurs

Tags: vue.js, typeerror, vuejs3, store, commit

Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')
[image]

[image]

If the login is successful, I want to send the data to the store.
However, an error occurs.

Please help me with why the error appears.

If login is successful in [login.vue], I want to send login data to the store.

**src/views/login/login.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="hello">
<div class="input_row">
  <label for="user_id">id</label>
  <input type="text" id="user_id" v-model="user.user_id" />
</div>
<div class="input_row">
  <label for="user_pwd">pwd</label>
  <input type="password" id="user_pwd" v-model="user.user_pwd" />
</div>
<button v-on:click="login">login</button>
<a href="/signUp">signUp</a>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data: function () {
  return {
    user: {
      user_id: "",
      user_pwd: "",
      user_name: "",
      Access_Token: ""
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  login: function (event) {
    this.$http
      .post("/api/users/login", {
        user: this.user,
      })
      .then(
        (res) => {
          // Login success 
          alert(res.data.message);
          if (res.data.success == true) {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.$store.commit('login',res.data);
            this.$router.push("/home");
            this.$router.replace({name: 'home'})
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          // error
          alert("Login failed! please check your id or password");
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  }
}
};
</script>
```

**src/store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import router from "@/router";

export default createStore({
  state: { user_id: null, user_name: null, Access_Token: null },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    login: function (state, payload) {
      state.user_id = payload.user_id;
      state.user_name = payload.user_name;
      state.Access_Token = payload.Access_Token;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

**src/main.js**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import Vuex from "vuex";

const app = createApp(App).use(router);

app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
app.use(VueAxios, axios);

createApp(App).use(store).use(Vuex).use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to commit in your action. You can then use dispatch instead of commit to launch the action.

Comment: so instead of this.$store.commit('/login', res.data) it should be this.$store.dispatch('/login', res.data)

Comment: @yesterday Thank you, but I solved it in a different way!
[main.js] I changed it from file to app.use (store) and it worked.